Using the New-AzSentinelDataConnector cmdlet
I have tried using the New-AzSentinelDataConnector cmdlet to create or update a data connector.
I have not fully gotten this solution working, trying to enable the Microsoft Entra ID data connector.
To emphasise this point, these were the PowerShell commands I ran:
$ResourceGroup = "rg-sentinel"

$WorkspaceName = "ingested-data-sentinel"

$Connection = Connect-AzAccount

$TenantId = $Connection.Context.Tenant.Id

New-AzSentinelDataConnector -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -kind AzureActiveDirectory -TenantId $TenantID -Alerts Enabled

Has anyone successfully deployed a data connector with this PowerShell cmdlet?
PowerShell Error

What is the exact error?

See the 'PowerShell Error' link. It states 'Licence is invalid'

I just checked that. To export sign-in data from Azure AD, you need an Azure AD P1 or P2 license minimum. @Jason Smyth

Is your issue resolved now! @Jason Smyth

The error is mostly due to the insufficient privileges of accessing the Microsoft Entra ID data from Microsoft Sentinel.
Go to Microsoft Entra ID and check the sign in logs, audit logs and other related logs are not greyed out for you like below.
If it is enabled for you, it means that you have the right on reading and writing permissions on Microsoft Entra ID for any operations.

And also check your workspace has a Microsoft Sentinel contributor and security admin roles to work with the sentinel AD data operations.
Refer MSDoc for more detailed information.
Note: As you are trying to connect to Azure Active Directory, the above should be done to avoid access denied errors. Once the above are done, you can successfully deploy this command.
Otherwise, if you want to create a connector for threat intelligence like given in MSDoc here, no need of adding any additional roles and it can be done as shown below.
New-AzSentinelDataConnector -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -Kind 'MicrosoftThreatIntelligence' -BingSafetyPhishingURL Enabled -BingSafetyPhishingUrlLookbackPeriod All  -MicrosoftEmergingThreatFeed Enabled -MicrosoftEmergingThreatFeedLookbackPeriod All


